# Unable to get value of the property ____: object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've researched the heck out of this. There are several posts on Stackoverflow about this already, but none seem to have an answer for me.

Like the other posts on here, it's working fine in Chrome or Firefox. But in IE 9, 8, 7, & 6 I get the same error. I've tried the hack where you force 9 into compatibility mode, but it doesn't resolve the issue.

It's saying `Unable to get value of the property 'styleHelper': object is null or undefined`, the irony is that if I – in IE 9 – type into the console `window.microstrategy.bone("W2552_Ctl").styleHelper` it works and returns the function I need (that ID was created by the WYSIWYG, don't hate me).

Yes, everything is wrapped in a `$(document).ready`. Yes, there are no typos. I do not get why IE hates this so much. Any help would be appreciated :)

The code in question is a simple variable declaration.

`var ctlBone = window.microstrategy.bone(targetId + "_Ctl").styleHelper.ctlBone;`

It appears that IE is trying to access that object right then and there rather than assign it.

Comment: You could maybe show the code that actually raises the error...

Comment: The code that raises the error is simply a variable declaration. It's not even DOING anything. Just assigning a variable. The "code" is `var ctlBone = window.microstrategy.bone(targetId + "_Ctl").styleHelper.ctlBone;`.

Comment: Are you sure `.bone(targetId + "_Ctl")` returns something ?

Comment: Yep! Yep! and Yep!

Again, this is working in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

I've console.log-ed every possible scenario I can think of and thrown in breakpoints. If I watch the object in the IE dev tools it shows up just fine.

Answer (score 6):

FINALLY!

It was an issue with a setTimeout. Apparently `setTimeout(function, miliseconds, param1, param2, param3);` breaks in IE specifically.

SOURCE: http://arguments.callee.info/2008/11/10/passing-arguments-to-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Comment: There was no way to tell you were even using `setTimeout`, based on your question. This is why it’s important to provide us with code samples.

Comment: My apologies. My JavaScript file is 1000+ lines long and those two particular bits are very far apart. Given my previous research on the subject I thought it was a browser specific thing with IE and how it handled objects, not the setTimeout.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest don't wrap you jquery code with in `$(document).ready(function(){` function. I have been also facing same problem after i comment that `$(document).ready(function(){` it is working fine in all the browsers including IE 9 8 7 .

Comment: This type of thing is better left as a comment.  Shouldn't take you too long to get the 50 reputation points you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the browser in compatibility mode  -   Tools, Compatibility View Settings, and select View all web sites in compatibility mode.